# Add option to javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, javadoc

I want to add some parameters like editor of the code to the javadoc, for example we have @author so I want @editor too. What should I do?
I went to *Preferences / Java / Code Style / Code* Template but after adding nothing happened.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create custom javadoc tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677564/how-to-create-custom-javadoc-tags) -- The standard doclet supports the `-tag` command line option for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only clean way is to add a Hook to the Version-Control.

Use a script and check if the `@editor` is not the committer: Cancel the commit! You need a few skills on shell-scripting.