# How to create custom JavaDoc tag in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

I want to create `@CreationDate` and `@ModifiedDate` JavaDoc tags to mention dates in JavaDocs. 
For example

```
/**
 * It's a custom exception specially designed for some critical events. 
 * This is related to the server's response.
 * @author Khan
 * @version 1.0
 * @creationDate 1 Jan 2016
 */
```

I found a way to do it in **Eclipse** here...

[How to create custom javadoc tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677564/how-to-create-custom-javadoc-tags)

But unable to find it in **Android Studio**. How can I add custom tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate JavaDoc with custom tag, Go to **Tools > Generate Javadoc**, Following screen will be displayed...

[image]

Now just add

> -tag creationDate:a:"Creation Date:"

in **Other command line arguments** text box.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to this section:

File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Javadoc issues > "Declaration has javadoc problems"

From there, you'll be able to add custom tags. See screenshot below with your example implemented:

[image: Screenshot example]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've already added tags from here, but after generating JavaDoc, these tags are not displayed.

Comment: After I did this the "wrong tag" warnings showing in the source-code editor went away.    Thanks.