# JavaDoc Tags in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am working on a program for a Java class and our professor gave us the JavaDoc template below to use for documenting each method.

/**
     * Description

```
 * @param
 *   
 * @precondition
 *   
 * @postcondition / return
 *   
 * @exception
 *   
 * @note
 *   
 **/
```

When I try to generate the JavaDoc for this program I only see the description, parameters and exceptions. The most important things, @precondition and @postcondition, do not show up. It would be nice if I could get @note to show up as well. I have tried manually adding the tags by putting them in the extra tag option when generating JavaDocs, but that doesn't work. I am working on Eclipse Mars 2.0. Is there any way to just permanently add these other tags to Eclipse?

Comment: When you say "I have tried manually adding the tags by putting them in the extra tag option when generating JavaDocs, but that doesn't work." you mean you did it like here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677564/how-to-create-custom-javadoc-tags

Comment: Yes, I followed those instructions and they did not work. However, the instructions below for "-tab <mytagname>:a:<tag text>" are working in my version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

@Precondition, @Postcondition and @Note are not supported by the default Javadoc.
You can either stick to the default ones (use @Return for example instead of @Postresult). All the supported tags can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm).

An other possibility is to create your own custom tags. This can be done by declaring your tag in the Javadoc options using `-tag <mytagname>:a:<tag text>` as can be found in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#options) (just ctrl-f '-tag')

Comment: Sorry for the typo, tks nitind for fixing that. If this answer solved your issue, please accept it.