# Tune DocLint to allow new tags in javadocs

Tags: java, java-8, javadoc

Is there a way to tune the DocLint (-Xdoclint) to allow new tags in javadocs?
Right now i get errors like:

```
error: unknown tag: checkstyle
     * @checkstyle ParameterNumber (3 lines)
```

I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation, I would like to define a list of tags that can be used (besides the usual `@param`, `@return`, etc.).

I don't want to disable those checks completely - I want to either add new tags or just disable the "unknown tag" check.

Comment: this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677564/how-to-create-custom-javadoc-tags

Answer (score 0):

For maven-javadoc-plugin >= 3.0.0

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0+</version>
   <configuration>
       <doclint>none</doclint>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For maven-javadoc-plugin < 3.0.0

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.*.*</version>
   <configuration>
       <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```